# Custom Control default backcolor

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I am working with some custom controls and I am having some major issues with them. All but one of the controls is not able to be drawn in the designer. When I open the designer for a form which had the custom control manually added to it the designer shows the error "The property 'BackColor" could not be created from it's default value. Error message: SystemColors.ButonFace is not a valid value for Int32. I do not set the back ground to SystemColors.ButonFace so this is very confusing to me...

The stack trace has the return line from this method as the last position from within my code before going into System code, this is in the _ControlName.Designer.cs file:

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Red")]
    public global::System.Drawing.Color BackColor {
        get {
            return ((global::System.Drawing.Color)(this["BackColor"]));
        }
        set {
            this["BackColor"] = value;
        }
    }
```

The one control that works didn't work before and now it suddenly does but it has exactly the same thing for this function. I can't seem to find what changed that makes it work now. If I change "Red" or "BackColor" nothing seems to change for any of them. I also tried restoring my backup and the one that started working still worked... I had someone else load up my backup and it did not work for them. Is this information stored somewhere outside of the project or something? I can't find anywhere setting anything to SystemColors.ButtonFace.

Thanks for any suggestions.